# Android GridView show images from different folders like gallery view + display thumbnail of a image folder

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing a application which will load image thumbnail from native code (C++) and then display in a grid view. I am able to achieve this and  showing images from a particular folder.
i Want to edit grid view and make collection of images and show as a image thumbnail of the new folder. This is something like gallery app in android jelly bean
I am very new to android development.
Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Ashwani